# Assigning a new coordinate system and projection to a shapefile in R

Tags: raster, r, sp, rgdal

I have a shapefile with no spatial reference nor projection, and a GEOTIFF that has the spatial reference and projection data. The shapefile was created from a segmentation analysis of the GEOTIFF, therefore the extent of the shapefile matches that of the GEOTIFF, and should be overlayed on the GEOTIFF. The two files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2UcSfPZijpGRnlOQUYwTG84QjQ?usp=sharing).

I have tried the `raster`, `sp` and `RGDAL` packages, among others, to try to project/reproject the shapefile. Due to the size of the shapefile, it takes over 2 days to `rasterize` from the `raster` package. I have tried to convert a smaller shapefile (`samp.shp`) to a raster, then copy the projection of the GEOTIFF (`geotiff`) to the new sampled raster.

```r
samp.shp.raster<-raster(samp.shp,res=r)
shp.rasPRO = projectRaster(samp.shp.raster, geotiff)
```

This seems to work on the sample, but I cannot get to reproduce it for my data. I think if I can convert the shapefile to a grid, then I can copy the X,Y coordinates of the geotiff to that grid, but I am not sure if this would work. I have >200 individual GEOTIFFs and corresponding shapefiles and I need to batch process. I am searching for the most efficient method of assigning the spatial reference and projection data to the shapefiles.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure from your question what exactly is the issue, but regarding the speed - maybe the package [velox](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/velox/velox.pdf) could help?

Comment: Thanks, I will try out the package. The issue is that I need the shapefile (with no spatial reference and undefined projection) to be assigned with the spatial reference  and projection of the TIFF file, so when I view them, on is "on top" of the other.

Comment: @user2507608 I analyzed your data yesterday. It seems that the shapefile is referenced nearly to xmin,ymin = 0,0. So If the layers have the same extent, one can add an *xOffset* and an *yOffset* to all the coordinated from the shapefile and the layers should overlay (like 'moving' the layer from one position to another). The offsets should be calculated as: *xOffset* = *xminGeotiff* - *xminShp* and *yOffset* =  *yminGeotiff* - *yminShp*. But I found that there are different offsets if xmin,ymin is used as the reference or xmax,ymax is used as the reference. So I couldn't make a transformation.

Comment: @ Guzmán Thanks for that insight.  From that I tried to locate the transformation used on the data, and it seems to be : `x' = 50000 + x*0.25` and `y' = 1529000 + y*-0.25`. I am thinking that it should give the same respective offset values. But dont know if this helps